# Get Namespace of an object using an Abstract Class or Trait?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, abstract-class, traits

I have some code such as the following:

```
namespace {
  trait ns{
    public function get_ns(){
      var_dump(__NAMESPACE__);
    }
  }
}

namespace a{
  class obj{
    use \ns;
  }
}

namespace b{
  class obj{
    use \ns;
  }
}

namespace {
  $a = new a\obj;
  $b = new b\obj;

  $a->get_ns();
  $b->get_ns();
}
```

Both `$a->get_ns();` and `$b->get_ns();` dump `string(0) ""` instead of `string(1) "a"` and `string(1) "b"`. The behaviour is the same if I use an abstract class instead of a trait.

This is (obviously) because the trait/abstract class was declared in the nomal namespace, however I'd like for the trait/abstract class to dump the namespace of the actual objects (a and b).

Is there any way to do this without creating this function in every object and without passing `__NAMESPACE__` as an argument to `get_ns()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [reflection api](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
var_dump((new \ReflectionObject($this))->getNamespaceName());
```

This is the kind of thing it's made for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get namespace from `$this`:

```
$class = get_class($this);
$ns = substr($class, 0, strrpos($class, '\\'));
```